# PasteSpecial xlPasteValues still pasting with formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following to copy a range from my template workbook to my active workbook. It copies as expected, except the blue cell background and border styles from the template are still pasting over. I only want the values of the cell. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Using Microsoft 365.

```
basicinformationTW.Range("B2:B9").Copy

basicinformationFW.Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Maybe you have some conditional formatting set up in the destination sheet or a `Worksheet Change` event code. BTW, a more efficient way to write your code, one that doesn't mess with the *Selection*, would be:  `basicinformationFW.Range("C7:C14").Value = basicinformationTW.Range("B2:B9").Value`, or a bit more dynamic `With basicinformationTW.Range("B2:B9"): basicinformationFW.Range("C7").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value: End With`, each colon designating a new line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: .Value was exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code w/o any issures on M365.

Please try a different approach.

```
    With basicinformationTW.Range("B2:B9")
        basicinformationFW.Range("C7").Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Value = .Value
    End With
```